# xcode Tools: Memory Leaks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

In the Memory Leaks tool in XCode 7 what do those crosses in the timeline represent (and the grey shape with the minus)? I could not find this in the documentation and they appear regularly on the timeline.

[image]

I get a long lists of leaked object (this is a big project developed in the last years). Should this list be always empty, or it's normal to get some leaks in a running app, or does this implies that it's bad written code?

[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya xCode 7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer the first question. The Leaks instrument checks for memory leaks every 10 seconds initially. If the Leaks instrument finds new leaks since the last check, it shows a red symbol with an X in it (the red crosses). The gray symbol with a minus sign means the Leaks instrument has found memory leaks, but no new leaks since the last check.

The goal is to get the Leaks instrument to show a green symbol with a checkmark. That means no leaks were found.

**Summary**

```
Green: no leaks 
Gray: no new leaks 
Red: new leaks
```

Comment: Nice one, +1. I didn't get chance to work on Xcode7.x else I could have given the answer as well....just thinking :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yeah I guess nobody is just thinking smartly as you, ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Just to have an idea: should this list be always empty, or it's normal
>   to get some leaks in a running app, or does this implies that it's bad
>   written code

No, it is not a normal thing and surely this is an ugly code with these many leaks.

If you are dealing with this application now, you should try to reduce to ZERO leaks, or minimise to an acceptable state(here I mean if some leaks are from some 3rd party libraries).

*Even I worked on a project that is in production from a decade with 2K classes, that doesn't have any leaks, but ever release we find some and remove it, otherwise the client will not accept the code.*

Comment: Thanks, what about the red crosses symbols on the timeline?

Comment: @Patrick: Sorry for that, will check and update you soon, I am still using Xcode 6.x. And here I do not see these red crosses.

Comment: Mhm, I'm not sure I've understood. "number of target" ?

Comment: @Patrick: Even I guessed. May be the app has multiple targets, by default its 2, one for the application itself and other for appTests.

Comment: And how do those red/grey symbols match with the number of targets? Are you sure you understood what I'm referring to? (the first pic in the question)

Comment: That's good, to remove the leaks for the client. Good client ;)